# How to run a PCA on patient transcriptomes with multiple factors?

Tags: r, statistics, pca

I want to make correlations for patient/control gene expression vs. age and disease duration, but first want to analyse if these are actually the major factors influencing expression. I therefore want to perform an analysis for the 6 factors that might possibly contribute. I've been advised to use a PCA, but am not sure whether this is the right approach.

The dataset contains the transciptome (~22000 genes) of 12 patients and 10 controls (22 total), at two sample locations (motor neuron/anterior horn)(making sample total 44). It also specifies age, sex, and disease duration and onset location if applicable.

It's structured like this:

```
                                   ID SAMPLE TYPE    SEX    LOC  DUR AGE   A4GALT    A4GNT     AA06      AAAS     AACS   AACSP1      AADAC  AADACL2
X14_MN_SALS_Female_Bulbar_1.5_73  X14     MN SALS Female Bulbar 1.50  73 8.157744 7.596196 5.686725  9.005752 8.774661 8.017204  2.6187541 6.123113
X16_MN_SALS_Male_Arm_2.5_61       X16     MN SALS   Male    Arm 2.50  61 5.608782 6.614755 5.021643  8.132393 8.305636 7.382119  2.3007358 5.644822
X17_MN_SALS_Male_Arm_2_55         X17     MN SALS   Male    Arm 2.00  55 6.352859 6.476315 5.361992  9.149753 8.285859 7.195165  2.8611876 5.262565
X18_MN_SALS_Female_Bulbar_2_80    X18     MN SALS Female Bulbar 2.00  80 5.861249 5.974864 3.626572  9.004500 8.490199 7.265542 -0.9157199 5.169626
X27_MN_SALS_Male_Bulbar_3.25_74   X27     MN SALS   Male Bulbar 3.25  74 6.902205 8.026182 4.425676  9.041460 9.064080 7.960368  4.5344159 5.813113
X33_MN_SALS_Male_Arm_6.5_54       X33     MN SALS   Male    Arm 6.50  54 7.738372 6.438547 5.155050  9.802918 7.978966 7.506638  2.6833762 5.603203
X34_MN_SALS_Female_Bulbar_1_81    X34     MN SALS Female Bulbar 1.00  81 6.275111 7.075491 4.739286 10.928380 7.158841 7.559285  4.0588992 5.389785
X35_MN_SALS_Female_Bulbar_5.75_74 X35     MN SALS Female Bulbar 5.75  74 7.007736 6.715060 4.855120  8.858147 7.781114 7.433698  1.4305219 5.381327
X60_MN_SALS_Female_Bulbar_3_58    X60     MN SALS Female Bulbar 3.00  58 7.038836 7.043665 4.976014  8.998403 8.721243 7.572964  3.2686456 5.485040
X63_MN_SALS_Male_Arm_2.5_68       X63     MN SALS   Male    Arm 2.50  68 6.856041 7.354628 4.261617  7.101367 8.851444 7.892859  1.9685346 6.089073
```

With the SAMPLE, TYPE, SEX and LOC set to factors and then integers, it is possible to run a PCA.

However, this results in the patients and controls being seen as factors (~22000 points of 44 factors), not the actual ones I want to include in this analysis (SAMPLE, TYPE, SEX, LOC, DUR, AGE). Is there a way to analyse the gene expression data using these factors?

Comment: The most obvious answer seems to be "use pca on the numeric columns of interest"? In general PCA is used to reduce the dimensionality of the problem. As such if you have 44 columns, using PCA you might be able to reduce this to 3 while knowing how much information is lost in the process.

Comment: Not the right approach. PCA works on numeric data only. Converting them to factors is not a reasonable approach. How would you interpret "Arm" having a value of 1 and "Bulbar" a value of 2? There must be published literature in your field analyzing data like this. Qualitative data could be converted into index variables (e.g. a variable for each sample category, type category, etc). That is probably what is happening if your 6 variables expanded to 44, but that probably be impossible to interpret.

Comment: @dcarlson: There is actually PCA for categorical (non-numeric) data possible, you either introduce a binary dimension (=column) for each possible value, or map it to a numerical value. Example for the 2nd approach: Take the column `SEX` for instance, you could map `female` to  `+1`, `male` to `-1` and `other` to `0`.

Comment: The first option is what I meant by index values. The second works if the is an underlying order to the categories. For example if the variable is cities, using alphabetical order would not give sensible results, but ordering by population size might.

Answer (score 1):

The package [PCAmixdata](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PCAmixdata/index.html) might actually be the thing you are looking for, more specifically the function `PCAmix()`

> Performs principal component analysis of a set of individuals (observations) described by a mixture of qualitative and quantitative variables. PCAmix includes ordinary principal component analysis (PCA) and multiple correspondence analysis (MCA) as special cases.

You find a minimal working example at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PCAmixdata/vignettes/PCAmixdata.html#graphical-outputs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133009/factominer-pca-with-factor-variables?rq=1 mitght also be helpful